# finite elements-exercice

Tags: numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

We consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the set of points $$\{M_1(-1,1),M_2(0,1), M_3(2,1),M_4(-1,0),M_5(1,0),M_6(2,0)\}$$

Let $\Omega$ a rectangular structure consisting of the heads $\{M_4(-1,0),M_6(2,0), M_3(2,1),M_1(-1,1)\}$

Let the two polygons $\sum_1 = \{M_4,M_5,M_2,M_1\}$ and $\sum_2 = \{M_5,M_6,M_3,M_2\}$

let the mesh $\{(e_1,\sum_1,Q_1),(e_2,\sum_2,Q_2)\}$ such $$Q_1=\{f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , f(x,y) = a + bx + cy + d xy , a , b, c , d \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

1- Prove that $(e_1,\sum_1,Q_1)$ and $(e_2,\sum_2,Q_1)$ are two finite elements of Lagrange.

2- Let $V$ the finite-dimensional space that corresponds to the mesh. Prove that $V \nsubseteqq H^1(\Omega)$

My problem is to prove 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any piecewise polynomial $v\in V$, $v$ restricted in each polygon has the form of $Q_1$:
$$
v = \begin{cases}
a_1+b_1 x+ c_1y + d_1 x y \quad\text{ in } \Sigma_1
\\
a_2+b_2 x+ c_2y + d_2 x y \quad\text{ in } \Sigma_2
\end{cases}
$$

Now we wanna argue that there exits such $v\notin H^1(\Omega)$. For $v$ is definitely continuous in both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ respectively, and it has $H^1$-regularity in both polygons. You can check $v$ restricted on $\Sigma_1$ is $L^2$ and so is its gradient, the same applies to $v$ restricted on $\Sigma_2$.

The only possible problematic part is where these two polygons intersect with each other: $\partial \Sigma_1 \cap\partial \Sigma_2 = M_2 M_5$.

The construction is pretty straight forward, we set $v = 1$ at node $M_2$, and zero on all other nodes, see if we can get a function that is continuous across the interface $M_2 M_5$ between these two polygons.

In $\Sigma_1$, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
&a_1+&b_1 (-1)+ &c_1 1 + &d_1 (-1) &= v(M_1) = 0
\\
&a_1+ & &c_1 1  & &= v(M_2) = 1
\\
&a_1+ &b_1 1 &  & &= v(M_5) = 0
\\
&a_1+ &b_1 (-1) &  & &= v(M_4) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
solving this leads to: 
$$
v\big|_{\Sigma_1} = y+xy.
$$

In $\Sigma_2$, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
&a_2+&b_2 2+ &c_2 1 + &d_1 2 &= v(M_3) = 0
\\
&a_2+ & &c_2 1  & &= v(M_2) = 1
\\
&a_2+ &b_2 1 &  & &= v(M_5) = 0
\\
&a_2+ &b_2 2 &  & &= v(M_6) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
solving this leads to: 
$$
v\big|_{\Sigma_2} = y-\frac{xy}{2}.
$$

Therefore, for a $v\in V$ satisfying that $v(M_2) = 1$ and zero at other nodes:
$$
v = \begin{cases}
y+xy \quad\text{ in } \Sigma_1
\\
y-xy/2 \quad\text{ in } \Sigma_2
\end{cases}
$$

Now it is up to you to check this function is not in $H^1$.

---

***Update***:

> please help me! i need an reference (book ) who we can found the definition of $V$ ($v\in V$ iff $v\in H^1$ on the two polygones and $v$ is continuous on $M_2$ and $M_5$ please.

I already gave you the reference in the comments. You are not satisfied with its presentation, yet I think it is crystal clear: Ciarlet's *The Finite Element Method for Elliptic Problems*, please refer to the proof of Theorem 2.1.1 on pg40.

The result is commonly used for finite elements w/o citing any references, and it is very straightforward to prove. It can be formulated as follows:

**Lemma**: Suppose $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are Lipschitz polygons, and $\partial\Sigma_1 \cap \partial \Sigma_2 = F$. Let $v_1\in H^1(\Sigma_1)$, $v_2\in H^1(\Sigma_2)$, and $v \in L^2(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2\cup F)$ so that $v = v_1$ in $\Sigma_1$ and $v=v_2$ in $\Sigma_2$. Then if $v_1 = v_2$ on $F$, we have $v\in H^1(\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2\cup F)$.

*Proof*: Let $\Omega = \Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2\cup F$. It suffices to show that the weak gradient of $v$ on the joint domain coincides with $\nabla v_1$ on $\Sigma_1$ and $\nabla v_2$ on $\Sigma_2$. Let $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$, 
$$
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} \,\phi :=
- \int_{\Omega} v \,\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} .
$$
This is the definition. The right side now can be divided into two parts:
$$
- \int_{\Omega} v \,\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} =
- \int_{\Sigma_1} v_1 \,\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i} 
- \int_{\Sigma_2} v_2 \,\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_i}
\\
= \int_{\Sigma_1} \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_i} \,\phi - \color{blue}{\int_{\partial \Sigma_1}  v_1 \phi \,(n_{\partial \Sigma_1})_i\,dS}+ \int_{\Sigma_2} \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_i} \,\phi
- \color{blue}{\int_{\partial \Sigma_2}  v_2 \phi \,(n_{\partial \Sigma_2})_i\, dS},
$$
$n_{\partial \Sigma_k}$ is the unit outer normal vector to $\Sigma_k$ ($k=1,2$). Blue terms will cancel because $n_{\partial \Sigma_1} = -n_{\partial \Sigma_2}$ pointwisely, and $v_1 = v_2$ pointwisely as limit from their defined domain respectively (or use a trace argument if you like). Hence
$$
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} \,\phi =  \int_{\Sigma_1}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_i} \,\phi + \int_{\Sigma_2} \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_i} \,\phi.
$$
This tells us $\nabla v = \nabla v_1$ on $\Sigma_1$ and $\nabla v = \nabla v_2$ on $\Sigma_2$. Hence 
$$
|\nabla v|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2 = \|\nabla v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 
= \|\nabla v_1\|_{L^2(\Sigma_1)}^2 + \|\nabla v_2\|_{L^2(\Sigma_2)}^2 < \infty,
$$
and the lemma follows.

Comment: @jijiii Oh I see, maybe we have a little misunderstanding. In stackexchange forum, "accepting" means clicking the check box outside the answer on the left upper corner of the answer, below the upvote arrow and the downvote arrow.

Comment: @jijiii And I suggest you go back to all of your previous question, accept the answer you are by clicking the check box. (If you don't know how to do, please refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask  ctrl+f accept on this page)