# variational question

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ a bounded domain, connexe and regular, and let $f \in L^2(\Omega).$ Let the variational problem: Find $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ such 
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v dx + (\int_{\Omega} u dx)(\int_{\Omega} v dx) = \int_{\Omega} f v dx, \forall v \in H^1(\Omega)$$
1- Prouve that this variational problem admits a unique solution in $H^1(\Omega).$

2- Deduce the boundary problem associate to this variational problem ( study the two cases $u \in  H^2(\Omega)$ and $u \notin H^2(\Omega)$.

I dont't understand in the question 2, why we mus study the two cases $u \in H^2$ and $u \notin H^2$?

Comment: Sorry about the question, but what is a limit problem?

Comment: sorry, there is a boundary problem.

Comment: Are you sure that there is this integral product? Is not $\int_\Omega uvdx$?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure for this.

Comment: Could you find the boundary value problem associated to it?

Comment: this is my question. How we can find it.

Comment: That's not your question: You have asked about $u$ being in $H^2$ or not.

Comment: isn't the associated boundary problem $-\Delta u + \int_\Omega u = f $ ? with boundary condition $ u = 0 $ on $\partial \Omega$ ?

Comment: please in the case $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ how we can use the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variation in Tomas' solution ?

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want you can add this in your question, but delete this.

Comment: The issue with the case $u \not\in H^{2}$ is the integration by parts. In this case the normal derivative along the boundary is not necessarily an element of $H^{1/2}$, but rather one of the dual space $H^{-1/2}$. There are still formulae of integration by parts, but things get tricky (you might loose surjectivity of the trace operator, you have to work with the duality pairings, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1: $u\in H^2(\Omega)$

In this case, we have that $$\tag{1}\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla v=-\int_\Omega v\Delta u+\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}v,\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$$

From $(1)$, we conclude that $$\tag{2}-\int_\Omega v\Delta u+\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}v+\int_\Omega (\int_\Omega u)v=\int f v,\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$$

If we take $v\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $(2)$, we can conclude by the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variation that $$\tag{3}-\Delta u(x)+\int_\Omega u=f(x),\ a.e.\ x\in\Omega$$

By using $(3)$, we conclude from $(2)$ that $$\tag{4}\int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}v=0,\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$$

$(4)$ implies that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=0$ in $\partial\Omega$, so your boundary balue problem is

$$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 -\Delta u+\int_\Omega u=f, &\mbox{ in $\Omega$} \\
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=0  &\mbox{ in $\partial\Omega$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

Case 2: $u\notin H^2(\Omega)$

I dont know how to treat the case. It is worth to note that the solution is unique, so I think that it is possible to prove that $u\in H^2(\Omega)$, by using difference quotient methods and then we are on the first case again, but this is just a guess.

Update: Suppose that $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ satisfies $$\tag{5}\int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla v+\left(\int_\Omega u\right)\left(\int_\Omega v\right)=\int_\Omega fv,\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$$

Take $v=1$ in $(5)$ and get $$\tag{6}\int_\Omega u=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega f$$

From $(5)$ and $(6)$ we concude that $$\tag{7}\int_\Omega\nabla u\nabla v=\int_\Omega\left(\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega f-f\right)v,\ \forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega)$$

As you can verify in [Brezis's](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Functional_Analysis_Sobolev_Spaces_and_P.html?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&redir_esc=y) book chapter 9, equation $(7)$ implies that $u\in H^2(\Omega)$, so the same argument as above can be used.

Remark: After the update, we note that the first part of the proof could be carried without distinguishing two distinct cases.

Comment: What is Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variation?

Comment: @TonyStark http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations

Comment: and for the case $u \notin H^2$ any one have an idea?

Comment: non idea for the case 2?

Comment: Did you tried to apply my guess? Take a look in the Brezis book chapter 9. There he does this type of accounte that I have suggested here.

Comment: i understand the case $u \in H^2$ very well, but i don't understand the case 2. i read that there is the same result in this case beacause $\int u = 0$ but i don't understand why